# Basics of kafka records with offsets and partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I am unable to understand the use of partitions and offsets in kafka.

1. When kafka record is sent, is it split across partitions or is the same message sent multiple times to each partition ?
2. Multiple offsets from multiple partitions make one record ?

Any idea ?

Comment: What have you tried to test your theory that anything is split, or duplicated? Write a consumer and print out the partition and offset value of each record and you'll be able to answer this for yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One record only exists in one partition, of one topic, at one offset.

A producer sends a batch of records at once, rather than one at a time, which can be split amongst partitions of many topics. However, splits are not mid-record.

If you did end up with duplicate records, it's because your code actually tried to send the record more than once. These would end up at different offsets, however.